# FluentValidation messages come in different languages ​and the message is not reflected on the screen

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I am using FluentValidation in my project. I use WithMessage in the definition, but the message I use is not displayed. Although I write a message in Turkish, an English expression appears on the screen.

The message I wrote for the priority field at the bottom comes, there is no problem with it.

TaskListValidator.cs,

```
public class TaskListValidator : AbstractValidator<TaskList>
    {
        public TaskListValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.TaskTitle).MinimumLength(5).WithMessage("Lütfen Konu Başlığı İçin En Az 5 Karakter Giriniz");
            RuleFor(x => x.TaskTitle).MaximumLength(50).WithMessage("Konu Başlığı İçin En Fazla 50 Karakter Girebilirsiniz");
            RuleFor(x => x.TaskTitle).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Konu Başlığı Alanı Boş Bırakılamaz");
            RuleFor(x => x.TaskDetails).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Açıklama Alanı Boş Bırakılamaz");
            RuleFor(x => x.Priority).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Lütfen Konunun Öncelik Türünü Seçiniz");
        }
    }
```

TaskListController.cs,

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddTask(TaskList taskList)
        {
            TaskListValidator taskListValidator = new TaskListValidator();
            ValidationResult validationResult = taskListValidator.Validate(taskList);
            if (validationResult.IsValid)
            {
                taskList.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                taskList.FinishDate = DateTime.Now;
                taskList.CreateUser = 1;
                taskList.Status = 1;
                taskListManager.itemAdd(taskList);
                Response.Redirect("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in validationResult.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(item.PropertyName, item.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

AddTask.cshtml,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddTask", "TaskList", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div id="divAddTask" class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-body p-4">
                <h5 class="card-title fw-semibold mb-4">Yeni İş Oluştur</h5>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <label class="form-label">Konu Başlığı</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.TaskTitle, new {@class="form-control", @placeholder="Konu Başlığı Giriniz"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.TaskTitle, null, new {@style="color:red"})
                    <br />
                    <label class="form-label">Açıklama</label>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(x=> x.TaskDetails, new {@class="form-control", @rows="10"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.TaskDetails, null, new {@style="color:red"})
                    <br />
                    <label class="form-label">Öncelik</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Priority,
                new List<SelectListItem>
                {new SelectListItem{Text="Lütfen Öncelik Durumunu Seçiniz", Value="0"},
                new SelectListItem{Text="Düşük", Value="1"},
                new SelectListItem{Text="Normal", Value="2"},
                new SelectListItem{Text="Yüksek", Value="3"}},
                new {@class="form-select"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Priority, null, new {@style="color:red"})
                    <br />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn mb-1 waves-effect waves-light btn-light-primary text-primary" id="btnAddTask">Oluştur</button>
                    <a href="/TaskList/Index" class="btn mb-1 waves-effect waves-light btn-light-warning text-warning">Listeye Dön</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you get the error message? From clientsid validation or serverside validation?

Comment: How can I understand this?

Comment: Client-side validation prevents submission until the form is valid,so if you add a break point in your controller,when you debug ,you could check if you get into the controller